Uniswap v3-periphery dependency downloads but cannot be found by solc
I'm trying to compile a smart contract using the apeworx framework in WSL on Windows. My contract has these dependencies:
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/interfaces/ISwapRouter.sol";

In my ape-config.yaml file I have the following:
name: TestContract
dependencies:
  - name: OpenZeppelin
    github: OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts
    version: 4.4.2
  - name: Uniswap
    github: Uniswap/v3-periphery
    ref: v1.2.0

I can see during ape compile that both repos were found and I have two directories in .ape/packages/projects:
OpenZeppelin_openzeppelin-contracts
Uniswap_v3-periphery

However ape compile fails with the following error:
INFO:     Compiling using Solidity compiler '0.8.28+commit.7893614a'.
Input:
        contracts/.cache/openzeppelin/4.4.2/contracts/access/Ownable.sol
        contracts/.cache/openzeppelin/4.4.2/contracts/security/Pausable.sol
        contracts/.cache/openzeppelin/4.4.2/contracts/security/ReentrancyGuard.sol
        contracts/.cache/openzeppelin/4.4.2/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol
        contracts/.cache/openzeppelin/4.4.2/contracts/utils/Context.sol
        contracts/FlexiblePayments.sol
ERROR:    (SolcCompileError) ParserError: Source "contracts/.cache/uniswap/v1.2.0/v3-periphery/contracts/interfaces/ISwapRouter.sol" not found: File not found. Searched the following locations: "/tmp/tmp3yk74hcb/TestContract".
 --> contracts/FlexiblePayments.sol:8:1:
  |
8 | import "@uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/interfaces/ISwapRouter.sol";
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

I can't seem to get past this. I've verified that .ape/packages/projects/Uniswap_v3-periphery/v1_2_0/contracts/interfaces/ISwapRouter.sol exists it just cannot be found by the compiler.

The worst place to ask a question related to blockchain. Received so much hate here. Anyway, it looks like you need to define the remappings.
name: TestContract
dependencies:
  - name: OpenZeppelin
    github: OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts
    version: 4.4.2
  - name: Uniswap
    github: Uniswap/v3-periphery
    ref: 1.2.0

solidity:
  import_remapping:
    - "@uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts=Uniswap-periphery/1.2.0"
    - "@openzeppelin/contracts=OpenZeppelin/4.4.2"

Reference

https://github.com/Aviksaikat/Ape-Usage/blob/main/network-configs.md#imports--mappings
https://docs.apeworx.io/ape/stable/userguides/dependencies.html#solidity-import-remapping

Also the oz and periphery versions are quiet outdated unless you have specific reason to use those versions always use the latest releases.
